# How to get all text from a webpage?

Tags: c++, qt, get, html

I would like to write a program which translates text with the use of google translator or bing translator. My program gets HTML code from a webpage but this code doesn't contain content(translated text). How can I get the full code like in my browser(ctrl + shift + i [in firefox])?

```
Translate::Translate(TRANSLATOR translator)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    if(translator == GOOGLE){
    link = "https://translate.google.com/#en/fr/text";
    connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, 
          SLOT(replyFinishedGoogle(QNetworkReply*)));
    }
    else if(translator == BING){
    printf("ups BING doesn't work.\n");
    }


    networkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(link)));
    //QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(link));
}
```

...

```
void ByGoogle::replyFinishedGoogle(QNetworkReply* pReply)
{
    QByteArray data = pReply->readAll();
    QString source(data);

    printf("%s\n", source.toStdString().c_str());

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Translate is free only when used via browser. The text to translate and it's translations aren't in the source code. If you want to use Translate in your project, you have to pay the fee and than use the [REST API](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest)

The problem with your approach is in the url. The `#` is only recognizable by browsers, and triggers some javascript (ajax) code execution. You should try and use:

```
translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=p&text=something&hl=fr&sl=en
```

but it doesn't return html output.

Comment: You are right, but when I download web page by browser translations are included in code.

Comment: @joker I edited my answer, maybe this version will produce some results.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I have another question, when I use bing translation i have the same problem(http://www.bing.com/translator/?from=en&to=fr&text=text) in this url isn't #. Is there any way to download all content from webpage(text of course:D)?

Comment: @joker Bing has free API, it's a good practice to use one. There's a documentation and some examples how to do it. You make a http request and download the result in some form. When downloading html I didn't find the translation there, it must be somehow inserted there by JavaScript, so that's not a good appoach